# Print server - want to catch print command

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, sdk, wdk

How should i know at print server whether any client has fire any command. or any way to hook into printer driver at printing driver at server

What is print server ???
How print server work in Window???
How muliple client will send request to single print server???
Is any utility is running???
Can anybody clear me on this things???

Comment: What do you want to do?  Monitor queues or get the printed data?

Comment: Your questions sound like you really might want to ask this on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: i want to monitor queue as well as get what is going to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Microsoft do provide some APIs for intercepting the print spool:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms802176.aspx

Good luck!